# I need to create an audio player with 4-5 melodies

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

I am new in Iphone SDK programming
I need to create audio player but without array. Melodies have names "sound1, sound2, sound3..."

My code here:

```
NSUInteger x;
for (x=1; x<=tuneNums; x++)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound%d" ofType:@"wav"];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        aSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error]; 
        [aSound setNumberOfLoops:0];
        aSound.delegate = self; 
        [aSound prepareToPlay];
    }       
}
```

All button I have and work great, but only with one mellody:( But how release 4-5 melodies i dont know :(

P.S. Forgive me for my english I'm just out of Siberia

Comment: Why are you allocating AVAudioPlayer numerous times? Can't you just allocate it once and then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating an AVAudioPlayer on each cycle, and you get only one 'melody' because that's the one allocated in the last cycle.

As 7KV7 pointed out, you should allocate one AVAudioPlayer when the user presses a button, play the corresponding audio file, and then release/recreate it when another button is pressed.

Something like:

```
- (void)button1Pressed:(id)sender {
    // release the current player
    if(aSound) {
        [aSound release], aSound = nil;
    }

    // create a new player with the first file
    aSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error]; 
    [aSound setNumberOfLoops:0];
    aSound.delegate = self; 
    [aSound prepareToPlay];
}
```

How to determine which audio file to play when a button is pressed is up to you. If you are going to have only four audio files, the simplest way is to have a fixed number of buttonPressed selectors (e.g. button1Pressed, button2Pressed) and associate them to your four buttons.

Comment: I considered the method of creating buttons, but the number melody can increase the number of buttons, too, and that would not be writing for example 20 buttons I created them using the cycle:) melody is connected to the buttons, so using the cycle for melodies

Comment: Then you could create the buttons dynamically storing the index of the audio file in each button's tag, and retrieve it to determine which file to play: int index = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;

Comment: I came across this before, but since there was no detailed examples on what TAG was not paying attention, if there is an example of something to share please!!!

Comment: From the docs: "tag: An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view later."

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right you should add the method-

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [player release];
}
```

and don't forget to set your view controller as the player delegate.

```
aSound.delegate=self;
```